# Как достать данные отсюда?

Tags: php, массивы, вконтакте

Мне приходит ответ от сервера

```
{"response":{  
    "count":1,
    "items":[  
        {  
            "peer":{  
                "id":2000000002,
                "type":"chat",
                "local_id":2
            },
            "in_read":0,
            "out_read":0,
            "last_message_id":0,
            "can_write":{  
                "allowed":true
            },
            "chat_settings":{  
                "title":"РђР»РµРєСЃРµР№",
                "members_count":3,
                "state":"in",
                "active_ids":[  
                    507091298,
                    484305448
                ],
                "acl":{  
                    "can_invite":true,
                    "can_change_info":true,
                    "can_change_pin":true,
                    "can_promote_users":false,
                    "can_see_invite_link":false,
                    "can_change_invite_link":false
                },
                "is_group_channel":false,
                "owner_id":иннфа и т.д
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Нужно отсюда достать local_id

Comment: О каком ЯП идёт речь? И можно более читаемый код?

Comment: PHP, мне через CURL идёт ответ от сервера в массиве каком-то, и оттуда нужно достать.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно разобрать что за json в вопросе, но по идее должно быть так:

```
$response = ''; // Ответ от сервера.
$json = json_decode($response, true);

$localId = $json['response']['items'][0]['peer']['local_id'];
```